# How to pick contact number from phone-book of android in to my application?

Tags: android

all
i want to take number from phonebook of android in my application database..
i have tried it with below code but here am getting name of person instead i want number from phonebook and want to store it in my database..how to achieve this????can any one guide me..

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(reqCode){
           case (PICK_CONTACT):
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                 Uri contactData = data.getData();
                 Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

                 if (c.moveToFirst()){
                     // other data is available for the Contact.  I have decided
                     //    to only get the name of the Contact.
                     String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE));
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance--

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code,

> ```
>    @Override
>    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent
>   data){
>     super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
>
>     switch(reqCode){
>        case (PICK_CONTACT):
>          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
>          {
>              Uri contactData = data.getData();
>              Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
>           if (c.moveToFirst()) {
>           String id =   
>             c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
>
>           String hasPhone =
>           c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
>
>           if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
>          Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
>                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
>                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
>                       null, null);
>             phones.moveToFirst();
>             String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
>           }
>             }
>          }
>     }
> ```

Comment: okey.....and if i want to show that particular number on textview on same layout then how to achieve it????

Comment: done..its working..thanks a lot.....but cursor is moving to next contact its retrieving same number for all contacts...

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is an old question, but I think the below resource *from* Android is extremely helpful on this matter. The "bonus" section is the exact code that raj was looking for. I think this link should be helpful to anyone who sees this question in the future, especially if you don't understand CapDroid's snippet.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    try {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = "";
                String no = "";

                Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    name = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    no = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }

                Log.e("Phone no & name :***: ", name + " : " + no);
                txt.append(name + " : " + no + "\n");

                id = null;
                name = null;
                no = null;
                phoneCur = null;
            }
            contect_resolver = null;
            cur = null;
            //                      populateContacts();
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("IllegalArgumentException::", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error :: ", e.toString());
    }
}
```