# How to programmatically open contacts pick with search filter entered programmatically?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, intentfilter, contactscontract

1. I want to open Contacts pick activity from my application with search field should be filled programmatically.
   Can anyone suggest what URI shoud i use or anything to put in intent's extra?

   ```
   private static final int PICK_CONTACT_SUBACTIVITY = 2;
   private void startContactActivity() {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
       // Here in this normally we pass number e.g. Uri.encode("987") but i want to pass name as filter is it possible?
       // I have also tried 
       //uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("pra"));
       //uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("pra"));
       uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("pra"));

       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
       startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_SUBACTIVITY);
   }
   ```

Can anyone suggest how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow :
[how-to-pick-contact-number-from-phone-book-of-android-in-to-my-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185815/how-to-pick-contact-number-from-phone-book-of-android-in-to-my-application)
or 
[developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html)

Comment: Hi omor4android i just want select contacts activity with its search field should be filled with whatever the filter i set programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to specify a filter programmatically.

The [Android SDK documentation states (in the chapter "Retrieval and modification with intents")](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#Access) that for `ACTION_PICK` you can only use one of
`Contacts.CONTENT_URI`, `Phone.CONTENT_URI`, `StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI`, `Email.CONTENT_URI`. This is indirectly a filter (all contacts, all with phone numbers, all with postal address, or all with email), but it is limited to this.